# Geographic coordinates in PostGIS to QGIS and shapefile layers

Tags: qgis, postgis, srid

I've got in PostgreSQL/PostGIS the table "points" with latitude and longitude fields. I've done

```
update  points
set geom = st_point (longitude, latitude);
```

and also

```
select updategeometrysrid ('points', 'geom', 3395);
```

In QGIS I've added that table with the Data Source Manager to a project in [EPSG::3395](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3395) with a shapefile layer already loaded. However, points from PostGIS table do not appear correctly projected. Any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: EPSG SRID 3395 is **not** latitude/longitude degrees -- It's [Web Mercator meters](https://epsg.io/3395). Use `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude),4326)` to UPDATE your geometry, and don't forget to build a spatial index.

Comment: Why 4326 instead of 3395?

Comment: Because 4326 is WGS84 decimal degrees (what you have). If you want to store 3395, you'd need to nest in an `ST_Transform( ddgeom ,  3395)`.

Comment: Agh, Vince! 3395 is not Web Mercator, but World Mercator.

Answer (score 1):

try as below which stores the coordinates in geometry in Geographic coordinates, then QGIS should be able to display the points appropriately on the existing layer which is in 3395

```
update  points
set geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(longitude, latitude),4326)
```

or try as below which stores the coordinates in 3395 coordinate system

```
update  points
set geom = ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(longitude, latitude),4326),3395)
```

Answer (score 0):

All updategeometrysrid does is set metadata for a program to correctly read the geometry type. Therefore, if the geometry is not actually recorded using 3395, any features position will be incorrect.

I suspect you need [st_transform](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) to get the geometry from it's original type to 3395

Comment: A `ST_Transform` would be necessary to change the geometry in the table, but QGIS should be smart enough to project on the fly when the metadata is correct. To make this a complete answer, you should not only state what's wrong, but how to fix it (in this case, including the option to either change the metadata to match the data or change the data to match the metadata).